# Why do languages use different symbols (. or ,) as the thousands separator?

Tags: numbers, numerals

Examples of the separators can be seen in this [Oracle number formatting chart](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html). It appears that the Anglophone countries use `,` as the thousands separator and `.` as the decimal separator, but other countries have completely different conventions. For example, Germany has the opposite convention to English (`.` as thousands separator, `,` as decimal separator).

How did this convention come about from a historical and linguistic perspective?

Comment: The [Decimal mark #History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#History) Wikipedia article has more than a comprehensive essay on this. I downvote this question for no own research prior to asking.

Comment: @bytebuster The link has no explanation to *why* that is the case, it more or less simply says that the different countries adopted different symbols. The closest it comes is from a Spanish source stating that the full stop was used in France prior to the separator, but provides no viewable citation.

Comment: This whole site is based on the dogma that wikipedia is the unquestionable source of all human knowledge. "Own research" means "looking it up on wikipedia".

Comment: @fdb no, of course not. But those who **at least** open up a relevant Wikipedia page would become aware about the **context**, hence tend to ask more specific, *answerable* questions. On the contrary, just asking "why?" is an invitation for an essay that hardly can be much different to what is written on Wikipedia. This is called "general knowledge" in SE community.

Comment: @bytebuster On the contrary, I *have* read the Wikipedia article prior to posting this question, but I didn't see anything on it that was worth describing in the question, as it simply provides a less complete list without any additional citations which would answer my question.

Comment: A why?-question on phenomena like this is usaully not answerable. There were several potential choices for a thousands separator, and different typographic traditions took different solutions (not mentioned here is the Swiss tradition using an apostroph as thousands separator, and German one using a thin space). You can ask when it happened and who proposed what, but why? We don't know.